# How to pay AWS charges if you are on free trial

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to learn how to use aws and for this purposes i have taken aws free trial,
however when i was doing some exersise/labs, i was charged for usinsg NAT's resoures.
I have deactivated all my instances but i am not able to pay my charges the system says:
**there are no payments required for this account**, i would like  to pay this charge, what should
i do to be able to make this operation?[image]

Comment: I'm guessing they haven't cut an invoice for you yet. You'll have to wait until the end of the billing period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any charges beyond the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) will be charged to your credit card after the end of the month.

You can monitor usage of the Free Tier in the management console.

A NAT Gateway in a USA region is charged at `$0.045 per hour` and `$0.045 per GB processed`.